# Searched item returns wrong detail view on click

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am parsing some info from `JSON` using `Firebase`. I implemented search controller into the `tableview`, it returns correct items while searching but the problem is that on click (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) it returns wrong info. What could cause this, can you tell me guys?

This is the arrays in which I am searching:

```
var brands = [String]()
```

And this is the filtered array:

```
var filteredBrands = [String]()
```

And this is what I am doing inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

selectedBrand = brands[indexPath.row]
performSegueWithIdentifier("toProducts", sender: self)
}
```

And like this I pass the selected value:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

if (segue.identifier == "toProducts") {
     let snusProductsView = segue.destinationViewController as! SnusProductsTableViewController
snusProductsView.brandName = selectedBrand
print(self.selectedBrand)
    }
}
```

But for some reason it passes the wrong value. It passes the first item inside `tableView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you have to check is it filtered version or not if so you need to use `filteredBrands` instead of `brands`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if isSearching {
        selectedBrand = filteredBrands[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        selectedBrand = brands[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Comment: Hahh.. I came up with the same solution by my self 2 minutes ago :D

Comment: I just made this mistake a few days ago :)

Answer (score 1):

I must be dumb... After posting I figured out what was the problem. My `selectedBrand` was wrong if the `resultSearchController` was active. So I fixed it like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){

    if (segue.identifier == "toProducts") {
        let snusProductsView = segue.destinationViewController as! SnusProductsTableViewController
        snusProductsView.brandName = selectedBrand
        print(self.selectedBrand)
    }
}
```